# Cron Job Scheduling in wordpress

Tags: wp-cron

```
    add_action('init', 'property_listing_check_status');
function property_listing_check_status() {
    if (! wp_next_scheduled ( 'daily_check_property_status' )) {
    wp_schedule_event( time() , 'hourly', 'daily_check_property_status');
    }
    add_action('daily_check_property_status', 'do_this_hourly');
}



function do_this_hourly() {
    print_r('vivek');
}
```

**I tried this code but i need to change time interval how to change this**

Comment: Just change "hourly" to what you need

Answer (score 0):

You an use following:

```
 add_filter('cron_schedules', 'add_scheduled_interval');
 function add_scheduled_interval($schedules)
 {
     /* add your time to 'interval' option, it should be in seconds */
     $schedules['hourly'] = array( 'interval' => 5, 'display' => 'Once 5 sec' );

     return $schedules;
 }
```